# Generate flow chart html from json or xml

Tags: html, json, xml, flowchart

I have a problem in my web project. I need a generator  which will generate flow chart(mathematically graph form) `html` structure from `json` or `xml` object.

Problem is that when generates flow chart  there have connection lines. I want to write algorithm for optimally draw this lines and place charts in screen. I thing there must be such libraries. But I can't find any library which generates optimal fow chart screen from `json` or `xml`(or any other object structure). I found such libraries :

http://raphaeljs.com/

for example as [form](http://www.google.az/imgres?start=90&hl=ru&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&tbnid=5oW9PELU1pvO9M%3a&imgrefurl=http://erasmus.ca/indexerslegacy/?p=136&docid=572yTM25K7iy8M&imgurl=http://erasmus.ca/indexerslegacy/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Flow-Chart2.jpeg&w=3691&h=2835&ei=gDkkUu_gFZOQhQfg6IHIAg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:16,s:100,i:52&iact=rc&page=3&tbnh=175&tbnw=227&ndsp=52&tx=30&ty=46)

Comment: Check out [D3](http://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a commercial solution, have a look on [yFiles for HTML](http://www.yworks.com/de/products_yfileshtml_about.html).